# Can't load 'mechanize' in rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize-ruby

In the rails interactive shell (`rails c`), I get a error that says: `No such file to load -- Mechanize'` when I run `require 'mechanize'`.

Curiously enough I don't get any error when I enter `require 'mechanize'` on the ruby shell (`irb`).

A sample output is shown below:

```
    rails c 
    Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
    irb(main):001:0> require 'mechanize'
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- mechanize
     from /home/********/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
     from /home/********/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
      from /home/********/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
      from /home/********/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from (irb):1
      from /home/********/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
      from /home/********/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
      from /home/********/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
      from bin/rails:4:in `require'
      from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Regards

Comment: You've added gem 'mechanize' to your Gemfile right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to Gemfile

```
gem 'mechanize'
```

then execute this command on the shell

```
bundle
```